# Golang Time parse issue

Tags: go, time

I am executing below code to parse a time

```
var time_format = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000+0700"
var s = "2018-08-23T14:10:31.692+0700"
p, _ := time.Parse(time_format, s)
fmt.Println(p.String())
```

The output of above program is as below.

```
2018-08-23 14:10:31.692 +0000 UTC
```

It is the same time in UTC while I am parsing a time which is +0700 ahead of UTC so as expeceted result should be

```
2018-08-23 7:10:31.692 +0000 UTC
```

Can anyone tell what is the issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your format string is not correct. The timezone indication must be `-0700` (not `+0700`). [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
> ```

With that change it works:

```
var format = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-0700"

var s = "2018-08-23T14:10:31.692+0700"
p, err := time.Parse(format, s)

fmt.Println(p.String(), err)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1Jz2rxFbOUq)):

```
2018-08-23 14:10:31.692 +0700 +0700 <nil>
```